# How to bake displacement map to different object?

Tags: uv, baking, displacement

I have copied a high poly mesh, decimated it and uv unwrapped it. Can i now bake a displacement map from the high poly mesh onto the uv map of the low poly copy and apply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have low an high poly mesh in the same position, enabled Selected to Active in Bake options and new image texture in each low poly mesh materials(if there is more then one) texture node. Then You select high poly mesh first and low poly second and hit Bake.If you would like to know more details, here is a good [tutorial on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTGTUd0pCaQ)